# Ssreflect probabilities (event and not event) sum to one

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, ssreflect

I am a beginner and would like your help getting to sum the probability of event F and the probability of event not F to one. Is there a fast way forward?

```
X: {RV (P) -> (R)}
F: {set U}
H: 0 < Pr P F
H0: Pr P F < 1
i: U
H1: i \in U
```

===

```
X i * P i * ((if i \in F then R1 else R0) + (if i \in ~: F then R1 else R0)) =
X i * P i
```

Comment: Please indicate what packages you are relying on.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like you need to rewrite with `inE` so that `i \in ~: F` become `i \notin F` and then a case analysis (`case: (i \in F)`) followed by `rewrite (addr0, add0r) mulr1` might suffice.